# Почему команда debugger не останавливает выполнение скрипта?

Tags: javascript, отладчик

> Выполнение кода можно также приостановить с помощью команды debugger прямо изнутри самого кода. [Источник](https://learn.javascript.ru/debugging-chrome#komanda-debugger)

Хорошо, я пробую это сделать. Пишу команду `debugger` до функции `alert`, по идее на 9 строке выполнение скрипта должно было остановиться. Но как я вижу, скрипт и дальше продолжает свою работу: `alert` выводит модальное окно.

```js
let global1 = 10;

function f1() {
    let a = 5;
    console.log(a);
}
f1();

debugger; //остановка выполнения скрипта

alert("The second alert");

function f2() {
    let a = 50;
    console.log(a);
}
f2();

let global2 = 20;
```

Comment: а консоль открывали?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы скрипт остановился и началась отладка кода - нужно обязательно открыть панель разработчика в браузере, чтобы тот мог автоматически перенаправить в панель отладки. Предполагаю вы просто её не открыли

Comment: Ах, да. Точно, спасибо) `debugger` работает